# "Math.round" is not rounding to the nearest integer correctly

Tags: javascript, algorithm, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6, math.round

Can someone please kindly explain to me why "Math.round" is not rounding to the nearest integer correctly? I have a 2D array, in which I want to find out the average of each columns.

```
const nums = [[ 20,10,35 ],[70,179,30],[207,223,8],[38,53,52],[234,209,251],[35,94,2]]
```

After transposing the each columns into rows:

```
[
  [ 20, 70, 207, 38, 234, 35 ],
  [ 10, 179, 223, 53, 209, 94 ],
  [ 35, 30, 8, 52, 251, 2 ]
]
```

I was able to return the average to be rounded off.

```
const avg = (arr) => arr[0].map((_,i) => arr.reduce((sum,v) => sum + Math.round(v[i]/arr.length),0))
```

Unfortunately, "Math.round" is not rounding the result correctly:

```
before  // [ 100.66666666666667, 127.99999999999999, 63.00000000000001 ]
after   // [ 101, 129, 63 ]
```

As you can see the 2nd element shoud have rouned off to "128" instead of "129". I've tried testing as followed without problem:

```
console.log(Math.round(127.99999999999999)); // 128
```

However, "Math.round" from my function is outputting incorrect result. Is this a glitch? Or is there something wrong with my function? Any feedback will be greatly appreciated, million thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to zer00ne's amazing tip, I was able to refactored the code to make the function work as followed:

```
const avg = (arr) => arr[0].map((_,i) => Math.round(arr.reduce((sum,v) => sum + v[i]/arr.length,0)));

console.log(avg(nums)); // [ 101, 128, 63 ]
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add everything first then divide `sum` by `arr.length` for an average?

Comment: How did you get the `before  // [ 100.66666666666667, 127.99999999999999, 63.00000000000001 ]`?  Your code calculates `113 + Math.round(15.666666666666666)` and the result of that is most definitely 129.

Comment: I guess by just removing the Math.round. But I agree with zer00ne. This is not how to calculate an average. In your case the average of [20, 20, 20] would be Math.round(20/3) + Math.round(20/3) + Math.round(20/3) = 7 + 7 + 7 = 21.

Comment: @zer00ne Dividing each element by `arr.length` before summing is fine. What's not fine is rounding each element individually, before summing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript math is at times inaccurate because it stores numbers in memory as binary floats, for details see [Why JavaScript is Bad At Math](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/why-javascript-is-bad-at-math-9b8247640caa). Anyways, if you're looking to have an array of three averages see the example below.

```js
const data = [
  [ 20, 70, 207, 38, 234, 35 ],
  [ 10, 179, 223, 53, 209, 94 ],
  [ 35, 30, 8, 52, 251, 2 ]
];

let output = data.map(sub => Math.round(
  sub.reduce(
    (sum, cur) => sum + cur)/sub.length)
);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips :) I was able to refactor the code and made it work: `const avg = (arr) => arr[0].map((_,i) => Math.round(arr.reduce((sum,v) => sum + v[i]/arr.length,0)));` Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.